# How to Ignore Cache If Session Set In Varnish

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I need to do custom Varnish VCL configuration for cookie based by-pass objects.
So, Varnish keep serving my cached pages unless user logged in. 
How can i prevent access to non-logged users? for specific pages or regex etc.

Using: 
Varnish 3 on Nginx, Ubuntu 64. bit EC2 instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the varnish default behaviour, excerpt from the default config [1]:

```
sub vcl_recv {
#...
  if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
    /* Not cacheable by default */
    return (pass);
  }
#...
}
```

[1] https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/vcl.html#examples